# Did Bhaktivinod Thakur explicitly employ the term 'apasampradaya' to describe unorthodox Vaishnavas?

Tags: vaishnavism, gaudiya-vaishnavism, iskcon

Bengali Vaishnava reformers in the 19th century reclaimed Vaishnavism as a noble indigenous tradition and rehabilitated its reputation, setting it apart from low-caste, antinomian, suspiciously Tantric, heterodox Vaishnava movements. For this purpose they employed the notion of apasampradāya – a term widely used by Bhaktisiddhanta Saraswati, by Bhaktivedanta Swami Prabhupada, and by his  followers. The term (apa- , prefix for inferior, bad, defecting, deviating, + sampradāya, a religious tradition, community, often translated as sect) is glossed as a deviant religious sect and used by orthodox Vaishnava spokespersons to refer to those communities that they envisage as degenerate, immoral, or unauthorized.

In the prolific writings of Bhaktivinoda Ṭhākura, is there any explicit mention of the term 'apasampradaya'? Can anybody provide a reference?

Comment: Perhaps this can help your research:  https://www.google.com/search?as_q=apasampradaya&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=nitaaiveda.com&as_occt=any&safe=images&as_filetype=&as_rights=

Comment: Thanks! I read the book but it often does not provide for detailed reference to primary sources...

Comment: Here: https://nitaaiveda.com/All_Scriptures_By_Acharyas/Bhaktivinoda_Thakura.htm you can go through his books and in your web browser search for the occurence of word apa-s ... or apas ... just first few letters will suffice for each book you read in the web browser.

Comment: Thanks @brahma jijnasa. Do you know if there is any digital archive of Bhaktivinoda's writings on the periodical, Sajjana toshani? That would be even more useful for these kinds of critical essays.

Comment: No, I don't know, but if your research is serious you can try contact some of the Iskcon's websites for guidance, such as Bhaktivedanta archives or any other  and they can perhaps help you.

Comment: Yes, I am in touch with Bhaktivedanta Research Institute and I visited their library several times. But this time they could not help my bibliographic search unfortunately. Thanks a lot for your comments anyway!